# Spring MVC Missing matrix variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to add a matrix parameter (or matrix variable) to my Rest Controller using SpringMVC (from Spring boot 1.2.3.RELEASE)
Here is my code :

```
@RestController
public class SubAgentsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{subagents}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public SubAgent subAgents(@MatrixVariable(value="agentName", pathVar="subagents") String agentName) {
        System.out.println(agentName);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to get :
http://localhost:8080/subagents;agentName=hello

that is the answer I receive :

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
>
> Missing matrix variable 'agentName' for method parameter of type String

What did I do wrong ? According to http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/reference/html/mvc.html that should work :-(

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation you linked to states,

> Note that to enable the use of matrix variables, you must set the
>   `removeSemicolonContent` property of `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` to
>   `false`. By default it is set to `true` with the exception of the MVC
>   namespace and the MVC Java config both of which automatically enable
>   the use of matrix variables.

If you're configuring your application by extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`, then override the `requestMappingHandlerMapping` method which prepares the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and set its appropriate property.

```
@Override
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
    final RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
    requestMappingHandlerMapping.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false); // <<< this
    return requestMappingHandlerMapping;
}
```

You'll then be all set.

---

With Spring Boot, I think all you need is to declare a `@Bean` method with the above, ie. that returns a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` instance.

Comment: right, thanks for your answer, that was it ! I would also add that for Spring Boot, you need to mark the class holding the RequestMapperHandling to to be annotated with `@Configuration` (not `@Bean`)

Comment: @AnthonyDahanne I'm saying the method needs to be annotated with `@Bean`.

Comment: I did not need to add this `@Bean` annotation to the method. Just the method you provided, in a class annotated with `@Configuration` was necessary with Spring boot 1.2.3 - this is what I'm using : https://gist.github.com/anthonydahanne/82915d8123eea9ff60b7 and it's working great

Comment: @AnthonyDahanne Oh, because you're overriding `WebMvcConfigurationSupport#requestMappingHandlerMapping` which is the typical solution I suggested. In Spring boot, I don't believe it's necessary. You can simply provide a `@Bean` method in a registered `@Configuration` class.

Answer (score 4):

In SpringBoot Application In order to enable Matrix variables you need to define below override code

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
        urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, they’re disabled by default

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Data and its controller mapping, try something like this also

```
@Configuration
public class DataMvcConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    public DelegatingHandlerMapping restHandlerMapping() {
        final DelegatingHandlerMapping delegatingHandlerMapping = super.restHandlerMapping();
        for (HandlerMapping delegate : delegatingHandlerMapping.getDelegates()) {
            if (delegate instanceof AbstractHandlerMapping) {
                ((AbstractHandlerMapping)delegate).setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
            }
        }
        return delegatingHandlerMapping;
    }
}
```