# How to resolve firewall.RequestRejectedException in saml

Tags: spring-security, firewall, spring-saml

After upgrading security version to 4.2.4,

we are getting below exception for url which contains semicolon

ex:

https://url/name=somevalue;value=somevalue

```
 org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"

        at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.rejectedBlacklistedUrls(StrictHttpFirewall.java:140) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

        at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:193) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:185) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

So, we did some configuration to custom implement of httpfirewall

```
      @Bean

      public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall()

      {

        StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();

        firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);

        firewall.setAllowSemicolon(true);

        return firewall;

      }
```

and

```
   @Override

    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception

     {

       super.configure(web);

       web.httpFirewall(this.httpFirewall);

      }
```

After configured, we are facing same issues.

Then I debugged the in-built class `StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(HttpServletRequest request)`

Sometimes we are getting nested request like :

```
firewalledRequest[ firewallwedRequest [ …  (request).
```

and I checked the `dofilter()` method in `filterchainProxy`

It’s not clearing `SecurityContextHolder`, and so `FilterChainProxy` actually occurs twice in the chain.

Comment: Please refer to this issue. A possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48580584/stricthttpfirewall-in-spring-security-4-2-vs-spring-mvc-matrixvariable/48636757

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StrictHttpFirewall in spring security 4.2 vs spring MVC @MatrixVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48580584/stricthttpfirewall-in-spring-security-4-2-vs-spring-mvc-matrixvariable)