# Due to incorrect request with special character % and ; Spring Framework throw full stake trace and tomcat is showing full stack trace in result

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, tomcat9, rest

If I send input filed like for GET /Users/{name} -- Name of User = "User1;" or "User2%" we can see the following response with full stack trace information. With this "//", "\", we are not seeing the full stack trace info in response. Based on my investigation I found that with for "%" and ";" has different workflows then other special chars like "//", "\" etc . It is going through [StrictHttpFirewall.rejectedBlacklistedUrls()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/firewall/FirewalledRequest.html) which is a private method of part of the Spring-Security-web framework.
and eventually, it goes to the tomcat embed core - [ErrorReportValue.report](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/efa4cfc4411d0bed86490ea7de22f6a7e33fbc22/java/org/apache/catalina/valves/ErrorReportValve.java#L285) class wherein HTML tags, all stack traces are appended to it, which we are seeing in the response.

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p><p><b>Message</b> The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String &quot;%25&quot;</p><p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.</p><p><b>Exception</b></p><pre>org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String &quot;%25&quot;
    org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.rejectedBlacklistedUrls(StrictHttpFirewall.java:325)
    org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:293)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:194)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
</pre><p><b>Note</b> The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.30</h3></body></html>
```

I do not want to show full stack trace information to the user. Maybe we could extend StrictHttpFirewall to catch RequestRejectedException and throws a new exception with metadata from the request and a suppressed stack trace. But I do not want to make override or making a change in the spring framework. Can anyone help me if there is another way to hide the full stack trace from the response?

I am using "5.1.14.RELEASE" for spring version and tomcat 9.0.30

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21061638/438992, https://www.baeldung.com/custom-error-page-spring-mvc, etc. Creating custom error pages is documented in various places.

Comment: Thank you for sharing those links. I thought there is a way not to write any java code, by defining in the property file, maybe we could achieve it. Is there any other way, do you think, is it possible?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25237686/2696260).