# How can I pass a value with '/' symbol as get parameter to my controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, url, httprequest

I have controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/products/{value}")
    public String get(@PathVariable String value) {
        System.out.println(value);
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

After start server I try to send a message like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/products/Mazda
```

and I see in console *Mazda*. But when I send value with a backslash:

```
http://localhost:8080/products/Mazda\6
```

I get an error:

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.

How can I pass a value with '\' symbol as get parameter to my controller?

I expect: *Mazda\6*

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to encode the path variable on the client side. Here is an example for Java:

```
URLEncoder.encode("Mazda\\6", "UTF-8");
```

The result will be `Mazda%5C6`.
The second step is to [allow the processing of requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48580584/stricthttpfirewall-in-spring-security-4-2-vs-spring-mvc-matrixvariable/48636757) containing special characters in their URLs.

Third, decode the string in the controller:

```
String decodedValue = URLDecoder.decode(value, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: client side is browser

Comment: each language should have its own method for this functionality, for example, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp