# The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";" in jhipster gateway

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-gateway

I using Jhipster microservice. In production, I get the below exception in gateway war file:

> org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"

There are some suggestions to remove jsessionId by filtering it:

[StrictHttpFirewall in spring security 4.2 vs spring MVC @MatrixVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48580584/stricthttpfirewall-in-spring-security-4-2-vs-spring-mvc-matrixvariable/48636757#48636757)

Is there any other solution to cope with this in Jhipster architecture?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question for Stackoverflow, you should probably report it on github as an issue and provide more details and maybe contribute a solution.